# How to get the remote machine command prompt output in python?

Tags: python, wmi

I am trying to connect the windows remote machine and executing the .exe in the command prompt. However, not able to capture the command prompt output

Working: Its connected windows remote machine using WMI and executed the .exe through Win32_Process
Not Working: Not able to capture the .exe output which is printing in the command prompt

```
import wmi, subprocess
import os, datetime, inspect, sys
import Trigger_Campaign_Sub as fn
from socket import *
...
...
connection = wmi.WMI(ip, user=username, password=password)
process_id, return_value = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="cmd.exe /c " + execommand)


process_id, return_value = connection.Win32_Process.Create(CommandLine="cmd.exe /c " + execommand)
```

This one give the process id for the execution, however i need the output logs printing in the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at this post:
[Run a command in a windows remote server and get back the console output in C# .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937167/run-a-command-in-a-windows-remote-server-and-get-back-the-console-output-in-c-sh)

Seems that running with psexec, returns the shell output on both ends, with the right setup.