# How to trigger batch file on remote server using C#

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, remote-server

I'd like to execute a batch file on a remote Windows server to erase log files on a computer that isn't in the same domain as me and for which I have login credentials.

I used the approach below, which worked but yielded no results.

```cs
try
{
    scope.Connect();
    ManagementPath mp = new ManagementPath(servername + "root\\cimv2:Win32_Process");
    ManagementClass mo = new ManagementClass(scope, mp, new ObjectGetOptions(null, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 5), true));
    ManagementBaseObject inParams = mo.GetMethodParameters("Create");
    InvokeMethodOptions options = new InvokeMethodOptions();
    inParams.SetPropertyValue("CommandLine", mCommand);
    inParams.SetPropertyValue("CurrentDirectory", workingDir);
    ManagementBaseObject mbo = mo.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, options);
    Object rv = mbo.GetPropertyValue("returnvalue");
    Object prid = mbo.GetPropertyValue("processid");
    _OutMessage = "success";
    _OutResult = true;
    _HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    _OutMessage = e.Message.ToString();
    _OutResult = false;
    _HttpStatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
}
```

Comment: Is this not working for you https://stackoverflow.com/a/10123561/713789 ?

Comment: My file is on a remote server, and all I need to do is trigger it to execute.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937167/run-a-command-in-a-windows-remote-server-and-get-back-the-console-output-in-c-sh

Comment: What should be the value for the command parameter? I am passing cmd resetFolder.bat and I am getting error

Answer (score 0):

The method I have used in the past is to enable OpenSSH on the remote machine, then use sockets to send commands to the remote and read the results back.

I would encourage you to explore the SSH.NET library (https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET).  This could be used to solve the problem.

Comment: I've already saved the file to my remote server. I just need to set a trigger for it to run from the client.

Comment: Are you wanting to run it on demand from the client, or from the server's task scheduler?

Comment: Yes, I need to run it as demand by the client.